# php script to find web server name

Tags: php, apache, nginx, webserver, varnish

Is there any php script to find the name of the web server like apache, varnish, nginx, etc.

I know about netcraft and wappalyzer, but I want to have a script to run in my local machine

The main reason is, I have 4 servers in my local machine Apache2, nginx, Varnish and Lighty.

I have different ports for them like localhost:70 localhost:7070 etc. But all the servers root folder is /var/www/ and I have one index.php in /www which lists all the projects under /www folder.

I need some php script to echo the server name to insert in my index.php file, eg: if I use localhost:70 the script would detect its Apache and will display Apache, so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the server information using `$_SERVER` method in php.

`$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` returns name like **Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10**

Comment: there is also $_SERVER['name'] but that will return the website name

Comment: thanks buddy.... I could do it by using $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] and $_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']. I have used Varnish in top of Apache, but when I do localhost:70 it shows only Apache2, as localhost:70 is varnish port with virtual host to 7070 Apache port. It didn't show because its just HTTP accelerator ? usually in wappalyzer it used to show all the web servers.

Comment: This does not work as of php 7.4 (haven't tested other versions)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER` superglobal variable with the index of `SERVER_SOFTWARE`:

```
$serverSoftware = $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
```

The above code gives you full name of server software. If you want to get just web server name, use this way:

```
$webServerName = explode('/', $serverSoftware)[0];
```

**Note:** The index of `$_SERVER` is case-sensitive. `server_software` doesn't work (as I tried before).

Answer (score 0):

Wappalyzer has a PHP port that you can run from the command line or a PHP script:

https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer#drivers
https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/tree/master/drivers/php