# how to identify the web server name of remote host

Tags: php

According to this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062632/php-script-to-find-web-server-name) it shows how to get the web server name for a local web server but how to do the same for a remote server by URL ?

i.e. `$_SERVER['software']` returns name like **Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10**

how can I apply this solution for a remote server - example here: http://browserspy.dk/webserver.php

I want to be able to specify the name of the remote server i.e. `$url = 'www.domain.com';` - I want to get the web server name as shown above for host name specified in `$url`

I am only interested in the web server name

Comment: Did you try $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] and $_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'] ?

Comment: yes, that gives me my local web server name (works fine).. however, i want the to get the web server name for a remote host, not of my own. I dont think i should be using $_SERVER as this is for local server only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method of doing this is using PHP's [get_headers(](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)) function which return the web-servers response headers

```
$url = 'http://php.net';
print_r(get_headers($url));
```

which will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx/1.6.2
    [2] => Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 13:21:44 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.7-1
    [6] => Last-Modified: Fri, 08 May 2015 13:10:12 GMT
    [7] => Content-language: en
    [8] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    [9] => Set-Cookie: COUNTRY=NA%2C95.77.98.186; expires=Fri, 15-May-2015 13:21:44 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; domain=.php.net
    [10] => Set-Cookie: LAST_NEWS=1431091304; expires=Sat, 07-May-2016 13:21:44 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.php.net
    [11] => Link: <http://php.net/index>; rel=shorturl
    [12] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
)
```

as you can see you have the `server` header which tells you that they are running `nginx/1.6.2`

or you can add the second parameter to the function which will return the allready parsed headers

```
$url = 'http://php.net';
$headers = get_headers($url, true);
echo $headers['Server']; //ngnix/1.6.2
```

Comment: this is what i am lookiing for but getting this error `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_header()` any ideas?

Comment: It's `get_headers` and not `get_header`.

Comment: @user3436467 they made a typo. See comment above and the edit.

Answer (score 1):

trainoasis is right, you can use :

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
```

**OR**

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']
```

**OR**

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: no, that is to get the **local** web server name.. i want it for a **remote** server i.e. `$url = 'www.domain.com';` i want the web server name for www.domain.com - makes sense ?